# PUT Data Successfully changed , but NULL in Database MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, crud, codeigniter-4

I'm testing put request on postman using a retrofit to MySQL database with CodeIgniter4. when I send a PUT Request to replace old data with new data, the notification log in postmant is success/200 OK . but when I try to check, the data parameters that appear all change replaced with "null".

> How to fix it?

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;
use App\Models\Modelmahasiswa;

class Mahasiswa extends ResourceController
{
    /**
     * Return an array of resource objects, themselves in array format
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $modelMhs = new Modelmahasiswa();
        $data = $modelMhs ->findAll();
        $response = [
            'status' => 200,
            'error' => "false",
            'message' => '',
            'totaldata' => count($data),
            'data' => $data,
        ];
        return $this ->respond($response, 200);
    }

    /**
     * Return the properties of a resource object
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function show($cari = null)
    {
        $modelMhs = new Modelmahasiswa();

        $data = $modelMhs->orLike('mhsnobp', $cari)
        ->orLike('mhsnama', $cari)->get()->getResult();


if (count($data)>1) {
        $response = [
            'status' => 200,
            'error' => "false",
            'message' => '',
            'totaldata' => count($data),
            'data' => $data,
        ];
        return $this ->respond($response, 200);

    } else if (count($data) == 1) {
        $response = [
            'status' => 200,
            'error' => "false",
            'message' => '',
            'totaldata' => count($data),
            'data' => $data,
        ];

        return $this ->respond($response, 200);
    } else {
        return $this->failNotFound('Maaf data '.$cari.' tidak ditemukan');
    }
}

    /**
     * Return a new resource object, with default properties
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function new()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Create a new resource object, from "posted" parameters
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function create()
    {
       $modelMhs = new Modelmahasiswa();
       $nobp = $this->request->getPost('mhsnobp');
       $nama = $this->request->getPost('mhsnama');
       $alamat = $this->request->getPost('mhsalamat');
       $prodi = $this->request->getPost('prodinama');
       $tgllahir = $this->request->getPost('mhstgllhr');

       $validation = \Config\Services::validation();

       $valid = $this->validate([
        'mhsnobp' => [
            'rules' => 'is_unique[mahasiswa.mhsnobp]',
            'label' => 'Nomor Induk Mahasiswa',
            'errors' =>  [
                'is_unique' => '{field} sudah ada'
            ]
        ]
    ]);

    
    
    if (!$valid) {
        $errors = $validation->getErrors();
        $response = [
            'status' => 404,
            'error' => true,
            'message' => $errors['mhsnobp']
        ];
        return $this->respond($response,404);
    } else {
        $modelMhs ->insert([
            'mhsnobp' => $nobp,
            'mhsnama' => $nama,
            'mhsalamat' => $alamat,
            'prodinama' => $prodi,
            'mhstgllhr' => $tgllahir,
           ]) ;
    
           $response = [
            'status' => 201,
            'error' => "false",
            'message' => 'Data mahasiswa berhasil disimpan',
           
        ];
    
        return $this->respond($response, 201);  
    }
    



    }

    /**
     * Return the editable properties of a resource object
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Add or update a model resource, from "posted" properties
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function update($nobp = null)
    {
       $model = new Modelmahasiswa();
       $data = [
        'mhsnama' => $this->request->getVar("mhsnama"),
        'mhsalamat' => $this->request->getVar("mhsalamat"),
        'prodinama' => $this->request->getVar("prodinama"),
        'mhstgllhr' => $this->request->getVar("mhstgllhr"),
       ];
       $model->update($nobp, $data);
       $response = [
        'status' => 200,
        'error' => null,
        'message' => "Data dengan No.BP $nobp berhasil diupdate",
       ];
       return $this->respond($response);
    }
    
    

    /**
     * Delete the designated resource object from the model
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function delete($nobp = null)
    {
        $modelMhs = new Modelmahasiswa();
        $cekData = $modelMhs->find($nobp);
        if($cekData) {

            $modelMhs->delete($nobp);
            $response = [
                'status' => 200,
                'error' => null,
                'message' => "Data berhasil dihapus",
            ];
            return $this->respondDeleted($response);

        }else {
            return $this->failNotFound('Not Found');
        }
    }
}
```

thanks for your participation and your kindness :)

Comment: Can you share your post data at your Postman?

Comment: '{
    "status": 201,
    "error": "false",
    "message": "Data mahasiswa berhasil disimpan"
}'

Comment: What I mean is the data you want to update.

Comment: sorry if  I misunderstood about what you meant, but to be honest now I'm confused by the "Post data" you meant.  what is the meaning of "post data" i have to share.... is you mean the form data structure in my postman or what?

Comment: or maybe what you mean is the code that I use to do the put/update request data based on the code that I shared in this post?

Comment: or the json data when i make a post request ?

Comment: hi @TicherhazFreePalestine , I just updated my post, if it's possible for you to have a look here is the   [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75904189/null-problem-in-api-put-data-request-to-update-mysql-database) . thanks for advance